# How different and efficient AlibabaTable Store is When compared with Apache Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cloud, alibaba-cloud

How different and efficient AlibabaTable Store is When compared with Apache Cassandra? I understand both are NoSQL Database. Can anyone please elaborate where and when Alibaba Table Store is preferred instead of Apache Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of Alibaba Cloud Table store as the Apache Cassandra because Table store checks all the requirements of Cassandra

The next thing when we talk about the benefits of Table Store compared to Cassandra, you need not worry about the below things when we use Table Store:

1. Scalability
2. multi-datacenter replication
3. Distributed
4. MapReduce support
5. Fault-tolerant

Well, Alibaba Cloud may not be using Cassandra at the backend, there is no mention of that.

All the scenarios where Cassandra is used, you can replace it with Table Store. But again I have not extensively worked with application involved Apache Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

If you read sample code for filtering, you will realized the differences with Cassandra. You will need use different data modelling in table store.